# How to programmatically clear buffers and caches in Windows

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, cache, buffer

I need benchmark the speed of some `bash` commands in a Cygwin environment, and ensure that the tests I'm running don't hit the Windows buffers or the caches. Although I'm doing the benchmarking in a `bash` environment, I suspect that all caching is done by Windows itself rather than Cygwin.

On a [Unix-based system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87909/216754), you can do the following to clear all caches and buffers:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

What is the equivalent to this command on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twisty is correct that there is no native tool in Windows to do this.

However, on doing some further research and testing, it seems that even SysInternals' Sync tool doesn't actually clear the memory used by Windows to cache files and data -  otherwise known as the filesystem cache, and which Windows calls *standby memory*. This can be demonstrated by using [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/rammap), another SysInternals tool that monitors all memory allocations in Windows.

Inspecting RAMMap's Standby Memory column before and after running the `Sync` tool shows that Windows' standby memory remains virtually unchanged before and after running `Sync`. In fact, `Sync` doesn't seem to have any noticeable effect on memory at all, which as far as I can tell makes it essentially useless for the purposes of performance testing.

I did discover an effective programmatic method to clear Windows' standby list, however, in the form of [EmptyStandbyList.exe](https://wj32.org/wp/software/empty-standby-list/), a simple command-line program from Wen Jia Liu:

> EmptyStandbyList.exe is a command line tool for Windows (Vista and above) that can empty:
>
> - process working sets
> - the modified page list
> - the standby lists (priorities 0 to 7)
> - the priority 0 standby list only

To use it, you need to ensure the *EmptyStandbyList.exe* file is in a location within your system's PATH environment variable, then  call `EmptyStandbyList.exe` from the shell or from within a script when you need to flush memory.

In `CMD`:

```
EmptyStandbyList.exe
```

And in `bash`:

```
cmd \/c EmptyStandbyList.exe
```

To confirm that Windows' standby memory has been successfully cleared after execution, you can again use RAMMap.

#### Before running `EmptyStandbyList.exe`

[image]

#### After running `EmptyStandbyList.exe`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent command built-in to Windows. However Microsoft makes [freely available](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sync) the **Sync** command, which does what you ask as far as for flushing unwritten data to disk. It's part of the SysInternals suite of tools.

Here's the [description](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sync#introduction) from its author:

> UNIX provides a standard utility called Sync, which can be used to direct the operating system to flush all file system data to disk in order to insure that it is stable and won't be lost in case of a system failure. Otherwise, any modified data present in the cache would be lost. Here is an equivalent that I wrote, called Sync, that works on all versions of Windows. Use it whenever you want to know that modified file data is safely stored on your hard drives.

You need administrative privileges to run the command. To flush the buffers of *all* disks, simply run:

```
sync
```

If you want to target only a single drive, such as `C:` use:

```
sync c:
```

You can also flush only removable drives with:

```
sync -r
```

This utility works on all versions of Windows from Vista/Server 2008 onward.

Comment: What are the differences between the Linux equivalent and this version? In other words, what other forms of temporary memory does Windows make use of that this command doesn't flush?

Comment: I don't know of a command to flush memory, but if you're OK with a GUI utility check out [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap). That said, I would caution that flushing memory on Windows creates a non-real world situation on the computer that may produce unrealistic benchmarking results. HTH.

Comment: I’ll check it out, thanks. Regarding the unrealistic real world situation, would that not be the case with Linux’s caching/buffers too or do those function completely differently?

Comment: @Hashim Unfortunately I've not used *nix systems in a professional capacity for years, so I couldn't begin to compare the differences between the two. Sorry.

Comment: The sysinternals sync utility was never intended to remove cached data from RAM. It writes out cached data that has been modified since being read from disk. Such data must be written to disk before a disk can be safely removed or the OS safely shut down. Even after writing to disk however the data may remain in RAM and will be used to satisfy subsequent read requests.